# Put raw emails into an IMAP account?

Tags: email

I am working on testing internationalization of an email reader application. As such I'd like to have a bank of emails with unusual subject encodings and the like to test with. I have been successful at identifying some emails with the headers endoded in specific encodings I would like to test, however I'm not sure how to successfully get the emails into an IMAP account (or alternatively a POP3 account would suffice as well) without butchering the existing headers/encodings.

With Outlook, for example, I can drag and drop messages into the IMAP account from my regular POP3 email account, or use the "resend" feature to send the message to a different account, however, with both of those solutions, outlook re-encodes the headers using it's own choice of encodings. So, for example, instead of the subject being base64 encoded, suddenly it's quoted-printable encoded, and I need it to stay base64 encoded.

So can anyone suggest how to get raw emails imported into an IMAP (or Pop3) account without changing the header encodings for fields such as subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some IMAP client, you can store messages to IMAP server.
One free C# IMAP client you can get from:
http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/Examples/

SotreMessage allows you store raw message to IMAP server.

Also if you have messages in IMAP server and wnat to ttransfer them, you can use IMAP sync application from same link.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for testing, set up an IMAP server locally, and store the messages on that. Choose some fairly transparent storage so that each message is a file on the server. Don't use an email client to write them, they are just text files (and in particular not Outlook!)